# How to create GWT JsArray?

Tags: gwt, gwt2

I need to convert values of type T into `JsArray`.

For example, I have String1, String2 .... Stringn. I need to convert these Strings into `JsArray` string.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You don't have much choices: creating a `JsArrayString` and adding to it, or using JSNI.

```java
JsArrayString arr = JavaScriptObject.createArray().cast();
arr.push(str1);
arr.push(str2);
arr.push(str3);
```

or

```java
static native JsArrayString asJsArray(String str1, String str2, String str3) /*-{
  return [str1, str2, str3];
}-*/;
```

Obviously, the latter doesn't scale, while being faster.

It really depends what exactly you need to do.

Answer (score 4):

Use `JsArrayUtils` like this:

```
JsArray<String> arr = JsArrayUtils.readOnlyJsArray(new String[] { string1, string2 });
```

Take a look at the javadoc:

> **com.google.gwt.core.client.JsArrayUtils**
>
> Utility class for manipulating JS arrays. These methods are not on
>   other JavaScriptObject subclasses, such as JsArray, because adding new
>   methods might break existing subtypes.

Answer (score 1):

Using generics, could do it like this:

```
public <T extends JavaScriptObject> JsArray<T> createGenericArray(T... objects) {
    JsArray<T> array = JavaScriptObject.createArray().cast();

    for (T object : objects) {
        array.push(object);
    }

    return array;
}
```

Obviously, `String` doesn't extend `JavaScriptObject`. You'd need to have overloads to account for primitive types. (Or, less safely, you could remove the bounds of `T` to allow for arbitrary types. You'd need to be much more careful if you were to do so.)